# PhpStorm/WebStorm: Is there way to adjust the font letter spacing?

Tags: fonts, line-spacing, phpstorm, webstorm

I am using a non-default font in Webstorm. I quite like it except that the letters are a bit too spaced, horizontally.

Now, I now that there is a setting to adjust the *vertical* spacing between lines.

Is there also a way to change the *horizontal* letter spacing?

Comment: Anyone? I would really like to have this feature. I am open to all hacks, tweaks etc -- modifying some configuration file, using the command line etc.

Comment: It looks like right now, you'd have to go to the extent of actually editing a font, specifically for use in PhpStorm. I'm coming up against this now where I have a font that renders nicely, but the letter spacing doesn't match Atom, or my terminal where it looks great. I like to have 2 editor panes side-by-side quite often so it's quite frustrating - and am looking at messing with some stuff in FontForge (e.g. that's how I customised my line-height in `xfce4-terminal` which doesn't have the option for it).